# Eliminar de una cadena en java todos los caracteres que no estén dentro del patrón

Tags: java, regex

Necesito limpiar la cadena de un String en java que obtengo al parsear. Esta cadena tiene todo tipo de caracteres, normalmente letras y números, pero también incluye símbolos o letras en otros idiomas. Lo que quiero hacer es eliminar todo lo que no sea números, puntos o comas, exceptuando la palabra `"Free"`. Es decir, si tengo por ejemplo:

```
String cadena1 = "AU$26.95 с уч. GST" //que me devuelva 26.95
String cadena2 = "Free с уч. GST" //que me devuelva Free
```

Hasta ahora lo estaba arreglando con `.replaceAll()` de esta forma:

```
cadena1.replaceAll("с уч. GST|AU$","");
```

Pero el código se hace cada vez más extenso, y todavía hay casos donde no consigo que se reemplace.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67946/discussion-between-pablo-simon-diestefano-and-jetlagfox).

Comment: Hola Jetlagfox, pudiste probar nuestras respuestas? Un saludo

Comment: Buenas @lois6b, tu respuesta era lo más cercano a lo que buscaba, así que la acepto como respuesta válida, que está además muy bien explicada. ¡Gracias!

Comment: @JetLagFox pero si tienes detalles que pulir, comentalos para poder solucionarlos xD

Comment: @lois6b Es sólo que no he conseguido hacerlo en un paso. El que si existe la palabra Free no me la elimine. Así que lo he hecho en dos, primero compruebo si tiene la palabra "Free", para el resto quito todas las comas o puntos, o ambas, en función de dónde se extraiga el precio.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Con la regex `\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?|Free` puedes decir que busque los numeros o el Free en la cadena.

Explicacion de la regex:

```
\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?|Free
```

- `\\d+` - uno o más digitos
- `(?:[.,]\\d+)?`

  - `(?: ...)` - grupo sin captura
  - `[.,]` - o punto o coma
  - `\\d+` - uno o más digitos
  - `(...)?` - al final, indica que es un grupo opcional. Puede o no aparecer.
- `... | ...` - operador OR
- `Free` -  coinidencia exacta con "Free"

Asi le dices que lo encontrado te lo saque y puedes guardarlo en una variable habiendo quitado todo lo que no te interesa.

```java
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

```java
String str1 = "AU$26.95 2.25 Freeс уч. GST"; 
String str2 = "AU$26,95  уч. GST";   
String str3 = "AU$Freeс уч. GST";

String resultado1 = comprobar(str1);
String resultado2 = comprobar(str2);
String resultado3 = comprobar(str3);

public static String comprobar(String elem){

    String all = "";
    System.out.println("Cadena: " +elem);

    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)?|Free");
    Matcher m = pat.matcher(elem);

    while (m.find()) {

        //System.out.println(m.group(0));
        System.out.println(" -  Coincidencia: " + m.group(0));
        all += m.group(0);
    }


    System.out.println("Resultado: " + all);
    System.out.println("");
    return all; 


}
```

Output:

```
Cadena: AU$26.95 2.25 Freeс уч. GST
 -  Coincidencia: 26.95
 -  Coincidencia: 2.25
 -  Coincidencia: Free
Resultado: 26.952.25Free

Cadena: AU$26,95  уч. GST
 -  Coincidencia: 26,95
Resultado: 26,95

Cadena: AU$Freeс уч. GST
 -  Coincidencia: Free
Resultado: Free
```

[Ejemplo de código online en Java](https://ideone.com/8BhzP4)

Ejemplo en JS para ver el resultado aquí mismo.

```js
const regex = /\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?|Free/g;
var str1 = "AU\$26.95 2.25 Freeс уч. GST"
var str2 = "AU\$26,95  уч. GST";
var str3 = "AU\$Freeс уч. GST";
let m;


var resultado1 = comprobar(str1);
var resultado2 = comprobar(str2);
var resultado3 = comprobar(str3);

function comprobar(elem) {
  var all = "";
  console.log("Cadena: " +elem);
  while ((m = regex.exec(elem)) !== null) {
    // Esto es necesario para evitar bucles infinitos
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
      regex.lastIndex++;
    }

    m.forEach(function(match) {
      console.log(` -  Coincidencia: ${match}`);
      all += match;
    });

  }
  console.log("Resultado: " + all);
  console.log("");
  return all;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> La mejor forma es [como te respondió lois6b](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/113711/127) (debería ser la respuesta aceptada). Sólo para jugar un poco, te muestro algo mucho menos eficiente, en una línea de código.

Podemos buscar que, cuando no esté seguido por un patrón, coincida con un caracter, o que capture el texto que coincide con ese patrón para usarlo en el reemplazo.

Eliminar el texto que no coincide con un patrón:

```java
r = texto.replaceAll( "(?:(?!patrón)(?s:.))*(patrón)?", "$1");
```

Descripción:

- `(?:(?!patrón)(?s:.))*` - Es un bucle, que va repitiéndose: si no está seguido por `patrón`, coincide con 1 caracter.
  `(?:`…`)*` es un grupo sin captura que repite la estructura (0 a infinitas veces).

  - `(?!patrón)` - es una inspección negativa ([*negative lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)) que coincide si la posición actual no está seguida de `patrón`.
  - `(?s:.)` - Un caracter cualquiera.
    Un punto coincide con cualquier caracter excepto saltos de línea. Pero si se usa el modificador s (*singleline* o [*DOTALL*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL)), incluye a `\n`. De esta forma estamos aplicando el modificador a esta parte del patrón.
- `(patrón)?` - Opcionalmente, capturamos el texto que coincide con el patrón.
  Nos va a servir para usarlo en el reemplazo, con `$1`.

---

En tu caso,lo simplificamos a:

```java
resultado = cadena1.replaceAll(
                        "(?:(?!\\d|Free)(?s:.))*(\\d+(?:[.,]\\d+)*|Free)?",
                        "$1"
                    );
```

Ejemplos:

```
AU$26.95 с уч. GST                       --> 26.95
Free с уч. GST                           --> Free
#$%&/=123,456,789.01xxxFree Free!!! 3:)  --> 123,456,789.01FreeFree3
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/HEYyV1

Pero, de nuevo, es una solución para vagos, no es lo mejor ni lo más intuitivo.

Comment: Gracias igualmente. En estos momentos he conseguido hacerlo funcionar, pero está bien por si tengo que necesitar seguir un patrón. De momento lo único que he tenido que hacer es hacer una condicional para "sacar" todos los casos que llevasen la palabra "Free" y al resto quitar parámetros para al final, en el caso de quedar algún caracter eliminarlo. Lo he probado con varios casos y funciona, pero tampoco me salva de que en algún caso no me funciona como debería. Gracias igualmente!

Answer (score 0):

En tu caso estás reemplazando exactamente esos caracteres por "" pero puedes usar un Regex en el replaceAll()

Por ejemplo, `[^\\dA-Za-z]`

- `^` Negación
- `\\d` Dígitos [0-9]
- `A-Za-z` Letras mayúsculas como minúsculas

Cualquier carácter que **NO** coincida con el patrón, lo reemplazamos con un ""

En la `cadena1` quieres quitar cualquier carácter que no sea un dígito o un punto:

- `cadena1.replaceAll("[^0-9]|.", "");`

Comment: No te olvides del "Free".

Comment: No estoy seguro de si añadiendo `"[^0-9]|.|^Free", ""` funcione

Comment: El único problema es que si tienes una cadena con varios puntos seguidos te los mantendrá

Comment: +1 para ti también, aunque lo óptimo sería dar la solución completa

Comment: @Orz un punto coincide con cualquier caracter. `[^0-9]|.` va a eliminar todo el texto siempre... Además, en relación a tu comentario, `^` coincide con el inicio del texto, y no es una forma de negar un patrón.

Answer (score 0):

Te paso un código donde dejar pasar puntos, números y Free.
Si tiene Free, puntos y números en la misma lo hace bien también.

```
String s="";  //Esto es una variable global donde se va a almacenar el resultado
public void comprobar(String aux){
    if (aux.contains("Free"))
    {
        int posF = aux.indexOf("Free");
        comprobar(aux.substring(0,posF));
        s = s + "Free";
        comprobar(aux.substring(posF+4, aux.length()-1));
    }else{
        compruebaResto(aux);
    }
}

public void compruebaResto(String aux){
    char[] cs = aux.toCharArray();

    for (char c:cs) {  //Recorremos la cadena
        if (c!='.')    //Si no es un punto comprobamos si es un número
        {
            try{
                Integer.parseInt(c+"");  //Si no es un número pasara al cath y no concatenará el valor
                s=s+c;
            }catch(Exception e)
            {}
        }else{
            s = s + c;  //Si es un punto lo aceptamos
        }
    }
}
```

Para llamar a este método desde el main sólo tienes que hacer:

```
String cadena1 = "AU$26.95 с уч. GST" //que me devuelva 26.95
String cadena2 = "Free с уч. GST" //que me devuelva Free

comprobar(cadena1);
//Hacemos lo necesario con cadena 1

s = "";  //Reiniciamos s para que no se concatenen los valores resultantes de evaluar cadena1 y cadena2
comprobar(cadena2);
```

Comment: Eso mismo lo hace el `replaceAll()` con una expresión regular...

Comment: He hecho este código porque el usuario ha dicho: "Hasta ahora lo estaba arreglando con .replaceAll() de esta forma:
cadena1.replaceAll("с уч. GST|AU$","");
Pero el código se hace cada vez más extenso, y todavía hay casos donde no consigo que se reemplace." Como dice, se le hace extenso y a veces no le funciona, este código si.

Comment: Seguro que tu código funciona, pero yo le recomiendo que refine la expresión regular, se ahorrará mucho código recorriendo un `array` de cadenas y pasándolas por el `replaceAll()`

Comment: Ahí tienes razón, se ahorrará código. Yo he puesto esta manera porque se entiende bien (lo he intentado explicar) y porque no manejo el tema de las expresiones regulares, pero teniendo ambos ejemplos, que coja el que más le guste

Comment: Genial, voto tu respuesta positivamente